# How to output error message when the conditions I set are not met

Tags: python

So I'm practicing programming and making a web page that takes in an `Integer` input from a user and outputs a fruit upon satisfying conditions such as if a `1` is in the number, or if it's divisible by `5`, etc. When a number that satisfies no conditions is inputted, I want to output `That is not a valid input`, but my code doesn't seem to work.

```
elif not (condition1(number) and condition2(number) and condition3(number)):
    result="That is not a valid integer"
    self.write_form(result)
```

However, when I enter in an invalid integer such as `2`, it renders a blank page instead of the error message.

Comment: I believe those should be `or`s instead of `and`s.  The number shouldn't pass ALL the tests, should it?  Need to see the rest of the code to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, that is not proper syntax.  `any()` tests a list.  `elif not any([condition1(number), condition2(number), condition3(number)]):`

Comment: `elif not any((condition1(number), condition2(number), condition3(number))): ? Taking from @GAEfan's suggestion, but I submit this as a bit clearer of intent. (retry, with enough parens to make it a tuple)